# How to access "this" from constructor parameter scope?

Tags: java

I'm initializing an object, and in the constructor, I am passing a lambda. In the lambda, I would like to access the object that I am initializing.

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject(params -> {
  this.xyz(); //Tries to access scope of class surrounding obj
  MyObject.this.xyz(); //Error: 'MyObject' is not a surrounding class
  obj.xyz(); //Error: Variable 'obj' might not have been initialized.
});
```

Example `MyObject` class:

```
public class MyObject {
  //Missing constructor

  public void xyz(){
    //Do stuff
  }
}
```

I would rather not pass `this` to the lambda if possible.

If there is a way to do a "temporary final variable", I can't find it.

Comment: A lambda expression is an object internally, so `this` would't not refer in any case to the correct object inside that context, I think you must pass it explicitly.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to access the object being constructed at all until it is completely constructed, that is after the constructor has returned.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `this`?  The lambda expression does not override it so it refers to the surrounding MyObject.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What surrounding `MyObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this, because the compiler must assume that the constructor is going to make full use of lambda, i.e. it could possibly call it.

In this case the call `xyz()` must be routed to an object that has not been initialized yet; Java compiler cannot allow that.

The workaround for this is to convince Java that you are not going to use partially initialized object during construction. You can do that by constructing the object first, and setting the lambda later:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.setLambda(params -> { obj.xyz(); });
```

One unfortunate consequence of this work-around is that the lambda variable cannot be marked `final` inside `MyObject` class.